# Manually recompile required if using custom launch-profile

Tags: asp.net-core

If i use a custom launchSettings-Profile like here described in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-2.2 , I have to build the Application manually to get the changes - also for simple changes in razor-html.

I create a new Asp.net core Web-Pages Application, I start it using Ctrl+F5. Now I can

1. make some changes in the HTML of the razor-file
2. save the *.cshtml-File **without rebuild**
3. switch to the browser
4. refresh with F5 (if I don´t use BrowserLink)
5. I see my changes - all is Ok

Now I create the custom launchProfile in Properties\launchSettings.json:

```
"HomeOffice": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "HomeOffice"
      }
    }
```

Also I create a *appsettings.HomeOffice.json* for my custom connectionStrings.

I select my new Profile in the DropDown-Box in VisualStudio, restart the App using Ctrl-F5. The App is running using the custom-configuration.

**But if I now make some changes in html, I must rebuild the project.**. This sucks for me!

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Auto rebuild only works when running with Kestrel (with or without IIS/IIS Express as a reverse proxy). In ASP.NET Core 2.2, the default hosting process model changed from out of process (i.e. Kestrel behind an IIS reverse proxy) to in process (i.e. running directly in the App Pool in IIS). I'm not sure what changes you made, but it likely just triggered a hosting scenario where the process model came into play.

Long and short, if you want to re-enable this functionality, you'll need to switch back to out of process. Edit your csproj and change the line:

```
<AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
```

To:

```
<AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but If create a new fresh Asp.Net Core-Application, auto-rebuild is running, also with InProcess-hosting (which is currently the default hostingModel). So switch back to OutOfProcess doesn´t solve my problem.